# Right way to create index organized table

Tags: oracle, optimization

I am trying to create a index organized table in oracle 11. I create the index organized table and insert the row from another table.

```
create table salIOT (
mypk ,
cid ,
date, 
CONSTRAINT sal_pk PRIMARY KEY (mypk)
) ORGANIZATION INDEX
AS Select * from another table;
```

But the leaf blocks are empty when I query

> SQL> Select owner, index_name, table_name, leaf_blocks from all_indexes where table_name like 'SALIOT';

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to gather statistics on the table, something like:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('ABC', 'IOTTableName')
```

(assuming `'ABC'` is your username; change as needed) - then re-run your `SELECT` against `ALL_INDEXES` and you will see how many leaf blocks you have.

Comment: let me try this